# Compilation error when starting eclipse plugin. Can't find libraries even though they are all there

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin for eclipse and from time to time (yes, sometimes it works, sometimes not. Then I have to clean the project and restart everything.) I get the following error when activating it:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle DeepRefactoring (501).
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
... 49 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
... 59 more


Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved
The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved
The import org.osgi cannot be resolved
AbstractUIPlugin cannot be resolved to a type
BundleContext cannot be resolved to a type
BundleContext cannot be resolved to a type
ImageDescriptor cannot be resolved to a type
The method imageDescriptorFromPlugin(String, String) is undefined for the type Activator

at deeprefactoring.Activator.<init>(Activator.java:7)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
... 62 more
```

All libraries are present (there are no compilation errors shown in the project).

Do you have any ideas where this could come from?

**EDIT:**

OK, so I kind of found the solution:
I had the plug-in project not only in my original workspace but also in the runtime workspace. For some reason, there (in the runtime workspace) it was not possible to compile the projects, it had errors. After closing the instance the project somehow remembered that it had errors and therefore it was now also impossible to run from the original workspace. 
Cleaning the project afterwards seems to work. Other solutions could be: removing or closing the project in the runtime workspace or disable automatic build there.

Comment: Well Eclipse thinks that `deeprefactoring.Activator` does have compilation errors

Comment: The Plug-in project does not show any problems or warnings in my development instance. And as I said, usually it works, just sometimes this error shows up. Any further ideas?

Comment: Do you use an external cmd line build on the same project file structure as is loaded in Eclipse? If so, you need to be refreshing and clean-building your Eclipse projects after doing a cmd line build.

Comment: No. I do everything inside eclipse.