# Eclipse Mars : The import org.osgi cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm using Eclipse Mars (latest version) to create an OSGI bundle with an Activator class.
For this, I'm using the Plug-In Project selecting "OSGI framework" to "standard" (but if I select "Equinox" I had same result) on creation.
The Activator class is empty for now but the compiler already raises me following errors :

The import org.osgi cannot be resolved
BundleActivator cannot be resolved to a type
BundleContext cannot be resolved to a type

Why ?

Thanks,
Paolo.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908211/compilation-error-when-starting-eclipse-plugin-cant-find-libraries-even-though

Comment: Have you added the `org.eclipse.osgi` plugin to the plugin's dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I solved.

The target platform wasn't selected.

Paolo.

Comment: It sounds like you are using PDE. Is there some reason why you need to use this tool?

Comment: I'm new to OSGi and in my understanding (following some tutorials online), the PDE is the way to create OSGi bundles under Eclipse, Is it wrong ?

Comment: PDE is *a* way to create OSGi bundles. Not the only way and probably not the best. You might want to look at [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/). Admittedly as the founder and lead developer I am biased... but it is quite popular.

Comment: However using Apache Felix works .. but using Equinox the console doesn't start. It's happen when creating a new Run Descriptor I select Equinox with builtin console instead of Apache Felix. Any idea ?

Comment: Unfortunately Equinox requires a configuration property to be set in order to enable the console. You just need to add the line `-runproperties: osgi.console` to your bndrun file. By the way this should be posted as a separate question because it will be more easily searchable by others who may encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, i have added the dependencies in the manifest file of the project

Go to META-INF Folder in your project where your are getting the error --> MANIFEST.MF --> Dependencies --> Required Plugins --> Search and Add all the OSGI Plugins there and save it